# Struggling with BIDMAS.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This question came up an I'm not sure about it:

You need to simplify leaving  the answer in standard form:

$\dfrac{2((3-3^2)^2)}{3+\sqrt{4^2-7}}$

I struggle to work it out myself. When I used a calculator it said 12. But you only get 12 if it's $3.464101614^2$. What do you think and how you worked it out.

Comment: Is your expression: $2(\frac{(3-3^2)^2}{3+\sqrt{(4^2-7)}})$?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your expression is:

$$2\left(\frac{(3-3^2)^2}{3+\sqrt{(4^2-7)}}\right)$$

Simplifying we get:

$$2\left(\frac{(3-9)^2}{3+\sqrt{(16-7)}}\right)$$

$$2\left(\frac{36}{3+\sqrt{(9)}}\right)$$

$$2\left(\frac{36}{3+3}\right)$$

$$2\left(\frac{36}{6}\right)=12$$